# Cocoa Touch: Displaying a structured document

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm fairly new to Cocoa and am having trouble Googling for the best way to design my iPhone app.

This app is for viewing a stageplay. It should pretty print the script such that character headings are centered and in small caps, say, and stage directions are in italics etc. It should also allow one character's lines to be highlighted (i.e. dynamic formatting).

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492177/cocoa-creating-a-custom-text-view) it looks like `NSTextView`/`NSTextStorage` will provide the formatting requirements I want, I'm just confused as to how to construct the view from the underlying data.

I'm thinking at the moment my source will be XML in the following form:

```
<script>
  <dialogue character="bob">Hello Sue!</dialogue>
  <stageDirection>He moves to the table</stageDirection>
  <dialogue character="sue">Hello Bob!</dialogue>
</script>
```

Which would output something similar to the following:

```
      BOB
Hello Sue!

   He moves to the table

      SUE
Hello Bob!
```

**How do I go from a document model (XML / CoreData / ...) to a view containing pretty formatted text?**

Any advice or pointers would be great; I just can't get my head around this problem!

Comment: NSTextView is a cocoa class and is not available in CocoaTouch. You cannot use this class in an iPhone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If interactivity isn't required then the most easy way I can think of is to generate HTML and render it with `UIWebView`. Dynamic highlighting can be done with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`

**UPDATE**

Next relatively easy option is to compose styled text with individual `UILabel`s. Basically you have an array of text entries (cues, stage directions etc.), each with it's own style. We create an array of corresponding `UILabel`s with styles applied and then layout them on "script view". After that we can put this "script view" in `UIScrollView` and that's it. Size of label required to fit particular text can be determined with `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` of `NSString`.

There are also CoreText services available, but this is much more advanced option.

Comment: I'd rather use Cocoa's native text formatting methods if possible and not go through HTML. It's an option I'm willing to look into though.

Comment: I see. The problem is that `NSTextView`'s counterpart in Cocoa Touch is `UITextView` which doesn't support individual styling of text's parts.

Comment: I think your second option is the one I'll go for. Seems to match my use case most closely. Thanks :)